# How do I programmatically translate a string?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am working on one custom module to alter the fields labels of user login form for visitors. I created a module to alter the labels in the user login form. The French language is enabled on the setup.

I am trying to translate the field labels on the user login form to French. I am using the following approach in a module.

I have included the namespace with `use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation`.
After that, I have debugged the `$form` variable inside `hook_form_alter()`.

From this debugged variable, I am trying to translate the filed label 'E-mail' to French.

```php
function hook_form_alter ({here goes all the parameters of alter hooks}){
  $form['name']['#title'] = t('E-mail');
}
```

I am not able to see the translated Email field label on the user login form.

Am I missing anything? What should I do to translate the strings using `hook_form_alter()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to programmatically add string translations?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214803/way-to-programmatically-add-string-translations)

Answer (score 0):

you have find and add your translation string here : admin/config/regional/translate

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But If i want to do it by including name space then which one I can include?