CPU high usage and database down after performing delete token
Whenever Drupal users create or modify from the Drupal Interface and rebuild the cache, then immediately the Drupal website goes down. when we check the logs there is an error as below,
This error we started observing in production after we changed the code and deployed. We did this change due to a deprecated function.
Previous: public function deleteTranslationSource($lid) { db_delete('locales_location')->condition('lid', $lid)->execute(); db_delete('locales_source')->condition('lid', $lid)->execute(); db_delete('locales_target')->condition('lid', $lid)->execute(); }
New Deployment: public function deleteTranslationSource($lid) { \Drupal::database()->delete('locales_location')->condition('lid', $lid)->execute(); \Drupal::database()->delete('locales_source')->condition('lid', $lid)->execute(); \Drupal::database()->delete('locales_target')->condition('lid', $lid)->execute(); }
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: UPDATE "locales_location" SET "version"=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE ("sid" = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND ("type" = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND ("name" = :db_condition_placeholder_2);
([:db_update_placeholder_0] => 9.5.7 [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1989 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => javascript [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => modules/Main/cms/js/dist/app.bundle.js)
DBA also got long-running query alerts, where the locales_location holds only 10k records and the table size is less than 2MB
We don't know why we see this error and its root cause. Please help out. Thanks
we are using Drupal 9.5.7 & MYSQL DB

Explain what this code example that looks like a diff is supposed to illustrate.

Yes, the first 3 line was existing in the production.. we removed the first 3 line and added the next 3 line as part of delete token.

Can you confirm you examined the database logs?

Yes, we could see the locales_location table size as 1.88MB with 10k records only.

We have drupal website (ex: domain/en/PAGENAME). After updating the content in drupal user interface, Rebuild cache performed. At the same time, we get more traffic to this page mentioned above.
@monalisa How all these are inter-related and causing db down, i mean to say, drupal user update in Drupal Interface and perform rebuild cache, at the same time Public users accessing that page.

Can you confirm you examined the database logs?

I guess @monalisa is asking if there is anything in the database log which would explain the lock wait timeout.

No, I have update the question with all the details I have. that's all we know as of now.

Where, when and by what surrounding code or script is this function executed? You need to tackle it down systematically. If it works on Stage but not on Prod, find out what's different. Maybe it's a different database, maybe it's a different server, maybe maybe maybe. You need to provide important context.

There isn’t enough information in the post to be able to answer the implied question, which I assume is “how do I fix this?” I would recommend engaging a developer or sysadmin to investigate the problem, the likelihood that someone could guess the cause from here is pretty low

There should be a better way of deleting string translations than removing them from the database directly.
Taken from this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220608/15055 I would start with something like this: (pseudo code)
  // Find the existing source string.
  $storage = \Drupal::service('locale.storage');
  $string = $storage->findString(array('source' => $source_string));
  if ($string) {
    $string->delete();
  }

Furthermore you need to pay attention that you batch the process correctly. If your function is part of a foreach-loop and is deleting hundreds of translations at once, running it without a proper batch process can result in having your database or server memory say goodbye at a certain point. 

Hi, We completed this activity and its been 2-3 days already, now we are getting this lock wait and cpu usage frequently in production after this changes only.

@Mr.V – You need to debug this yourself.

In Drupal 7, you could delete strings from the UI.
In Drupal 8, it seems that porting this feature was accidentally overlooked.  There is an MR to restore deleting strings from the UI, which is safer than deleting strings from the db directly.
Of course, with this approach, you have to delete the strings one-by-one.
On the plus side, this should not have any performance problems, and should not cause the db to go down. Also, since it's in the UI, even a non-programmer should be able to do string cleanup.

We are using Drupal 9.5.7, Will these codes cause performance issues in MYSQL, as I have seen these codes are recommended in Drupal 10.x version.
\Drupal::database()->delete('locales_location')->condition('lid', $lid)->execute();

As I said in my answer, if you delete the strings one at a time, there definitely should be no performance issue unless something is really wrong with your site configuration.  I can't comment on code performance for your code; it depends on how many strings you are trying to delete and what kind of machine you are running the code on.
